# if conditions in checking location

Tags: c++

I'm solving this problem and I am stuck on the two other if comditionsI have. I'm not sure how to check from **b to g** or **2-7**. I'm also confused on how to check if all 8 spots are available. I always get confused when iterating or checking code with if and for loops. Here is what I have so far:
 Problem:
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/710/a

Code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  string c;

  cin >> c;

  if(c == "a8" || c == "h8" || c == "a1" || c == h1){

    cout << "3 moves only available\n" << endl;
  }
  // confused on this case
   if(c == c[0]( ){

      cout << "5 moves only available\n" << endl;

    }
     // and this case
    if(c ==){

      cout << "all 8 moves are available\n" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that the code doesn't compile. What do you think the first error is?

Comment: What is `h1`? `c == c[0] ()`?

Comment: The note was already taken before submitting this @Cheersandhth.-Alf and *h1* is a corner spot that must be checked, and **c == c[0]()** is a spot where *// confused on this case*, basically trying to check rows and columns

Comment: Well, start by getting the syntax right, making the code compile. Then consider the logic errors. Voting to close as lacking relevant example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `h1` should be in inverted commas as it is a string literal, should look like this instead `"h1"`.

Second, the case when there are only 5 moves are along the side of the board (but not corners). Thus you only need check if the file (column) is `'a'` or `'h'` or if the rank (row) is `'1'` or `'8'`. Use `else if` to shortened to code so that you don't output twice if  it is a corner.

So your second case can look like this:

```
else if (c[0] == 'a' || c[0] == 'h' || c[1] == '1' || c[1] == '8){
    cout << "5 moves only available\n" << endl;
}
```

The last case is just:

```
else{
    cout << "all 8 moves only available\n" << endl;
}
```

as all other cases have been dealt with

Comment: I ran the code and it failed on a test case, in particular h1, it outputted 5 instead of 3 but i can't figure out why @Benson Lin edit: never mind, found it